# extract labelled words using regex perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex using perl but I need some help.
What I want to do is the following, suppose that I have these texts as examples:

1- [NP some/NN text/NNP here/NNP]

I am interested in the words labelled by /NNP, so I want my regex to search every line until it finds:
[NP then a space then (may or may not find) a word labeled with /NN then one or more words labelled with /NNP (and would contain some special characters).

I want to extract the words labelled with /NNP from each line so the result would be:

1- text here

what I have done so far is to extract the labelled words with /NNP from all the examples

```
while ($line =~ m/\s(\S*?)\/NNP/gs)
{
        my $word = $1;
        print $word." ";
} 
print "\n";
```

Any Ideas pleas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    while (<DATA>) {
        while ( m{(\[NP.+?\])}g ) {
        my $piece = $1;
        1 while $piece =~ m{(\w+)/NNP}g and printf "%s ",$1;
        print "\n";
        }
    }
    __DATA__
    1- [NP Almst$Ar/NN Ebd/NNP AlmEz/NNP AbrAhym/NNP] [NP Almhnds/NN hAnY/NNP HjAb/NNP]
    2- [NP xAld/NNP ftH/NNP Allh/NNP] [NP ESAm/NNP $rf/NNP] [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]
```

And then you asked to be able to skip lines with only one labeled word.  For that, I might do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @line = ();
while (<DATA>) {
    while ( m{(\[NP.+?\])}g ) {
        my $piece = $1;
        while ( $piece =~ m{(\w+)/NNP}g ) {
            push @line, $1;
        }
        print "@line\n", @line = () if @line && @line > 1;
    }
}
__DATA__
1- [NP Almst$Ar/NN Ebd/NNP AlmEz/NNP AbrAhym/NNP] [NP Almhnds/NN hAnY/NNP HjAb/NNP]
2- [NP xAld/NNP ftH/NNP Allh/NNP] [NP ESAm/NNP $rf/NNP] [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]
3- [Nothing of interest here]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but what if I don't want to extract ` [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]` which contains only one labelled word /NNP?

Answer (score 2):

First the golf:

```
my @list = map { [ /(\S+)\/NNP/g ] } map { ( /\[NP ([^\]]+)]/g ) } <DATA>;
```

- We take all the lines in the input
- We get all instances of `'[NP...]'`
- For each instance, we map it into an array of all the instances of `'*/NNP'`.

A little more long hand, it's like this:

```
my @list;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) { 
    foreach my $g ( $line =~ /\[NP ([^\]]+)]/g ) { 
        push @list, [ $g =~ /(\S+)\/NNP/g ];
    }
}
```

The dump looks like this:

```
@list: [
         [
           'Ebd',
           'AlmEz',
           'AbrAhym'
         ],
         [
           'hAnY',
           'HjAb'
         ],
         [
           'xAld',
           'ftH',
           'Allh'
         ],
         [
           'ESAm',
           '$rf'
         ],
         [
           'AlqAhrp'
         ]
       ]
```

---

(Responding to comment) There are two ways to print out the structure as I have above. The more standard way is something like:

```
use Data::Dumper ();
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@list ], [ '*list' ] );
```

The second is what I use:

```
use Smart::Comments;
### @list
```

See [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments). (Which pretty much does the same thing behind the scenes.)

Comment: @Axeman: Thank you. I am a newbie in perl, please how could I print `@list`, when i use the ordinary print it gives: `ARRAY(0x104a1488)ARRAY(0x104a1470)`.    Also what if I don't want to extract ` [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]` which contains only one labelled word /NNP?

Comment: @Daisy, see revised answer after the break.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, many good answers already. Here's a solution based on `split`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # for say(), not required

while (<DATA>) {
    for (grep /^\[NP /,                 # ..and keep only the NP-blocks
        split(/(\[NP [^]]*\])/, $_)) {  # Split on NP-blocks
        my @a = map { (split m(/), $_)[0] }    # ...keep first part
            grep m{/NNP\]?$},                  # ...and keep only /NNP
            split;                      # Split the NP-block on whitespace
        say "@a";
    }
}

__DATA__
[NP Almst$Ar/NN Ebd/NNP AlmEz/NNP AbrAhym/NNP] [NP Almhnds/NN hAnY/NNP HjAb/NNP]
[NP xAld/NNP ftH/NNP Allh/NNP] [NP ESAm/NNP $rf/NNP] [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $text = <<'DAISY';
[NP Almst$Ar/NN Ebd/NNP AlmEz/NNP AbrAhym/NNP] [NP Almhnds/NN hAnY/NNP HjAb/NNP]
[NP xAld/NNP ftH/NNP Allh/NNP] [NP ESAm/NNP $rf/NNP] [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]
DAISY

for my $tag ($text =~ /(\[NP.+?\/NNP\])/gm) {

    my @words = $tag =~ / (\w+)\/NNP/g;
    print "@words\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know a little perl, this should point you in the right direction:

```
$str = '
1- [NP Almst$Ar/NN Ebd/NNP AlmEz/NNP AbrAhym/NNP] [NP Almhnds/NN hAnY/NNP HjAb/NNP]
2- [NP xAld/NNP ftH/NNP Allh/NNP] [NP ESAm/NNP $rf/NNP] [NP AlqAhrp/NNP]
';

while ($str =~ /\[NP([^\]]+)\]/g)
{
    for ( $1 =~ /\s(\S*?)\/NNP/g)  {
        print "$_ ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```